# How to link editext to button in google map

Tags: android

Here is my java file.The code is simple google map where i want to pass a name to  the button and which should be searched on map.But my value is not getting pass to the button. Getting an error Null Pointer Exception in google map code while passing editext value to buttton.I am not able to understand what went wrong in coding.Whether i am wrong in adding value to tittle in marker or i m giving wrong value of editext to tittle in marker.Can anyone suggest how to pass editext value to my tittle in marker or to a button.

```
package com.example.test2;


import com.google.android.gms.drive.internal.f;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    Button btn1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.google_map);

        final EditText edt_text=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt1);

       // setText();

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                GoogleMap map;


                    map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
                    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);

                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(13.05241, 80.25082);
                    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(edt_text.getText().toString()));

                }

        });



    }


    }
```

logcat:

```
08-21 03:24:08.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1241): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-21 03:24:08.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1241): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-21 03:24:08.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1241):     at com.example.test2.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:42)
08-21 03:24:08.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1241):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
08-21 03:24:08.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1241):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
08-21 03:24:08.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1241):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
08-21 03:24:08.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1241):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-21 03:24:08.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1241):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-21 03:24:08.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1241):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
08-21 03:24:08.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1241):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-21 03:24:08.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1241):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the [Google Maps Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map)

Your activity must implement the `OnMapReadyCallback` interface. When the map is ready add the `onClickListener`

Y would say that your code is failing because the map has not been loaded yet when you call `getMap()`

Answer (score 0):

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            GoogleMap map;


                map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
                map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);

                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(13.05241, 80.25082);
        if(!(edt_text.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) 
                map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(edt_text.getText().toString()));

            }

    });
```